# Is this proof sufficient?

Tags: functions, solution-verification, hyperbolic-functions

I have two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, where $0<x<1$. I want to prove that $f(x)>g(x)$ on the mentioned domain (Plots of the functions verify this).

**Proof:**
I assume by contradiction that $f(x)\leq g(x)$. Then, after simplifying this condition, I arrive at a new condition

$h(x)\leq x\quad (1)$,

Then, calculating the value of $h$ at the endpoints of the domain, I get:

$\lim_{x\to 0} \, h(x)=0 \quad and \quad \lim_{x\to 1} \, h(x)=5$

Now, for the equal sign in Eq. (1), for $x=1$, we have $5=1$ which is a contradiction. And, if the inequality sign holds in (1), it yields the range of $h$ as $(0,1)$, while from the limit above, we know that $h(1)=5$ which is greater than $1$.

Then, can we conclude that the proposition is false and $f$ has to be greater than $g$?

Any comment is appreciated.

Comment: @PeterForeman I had written the functions (big and ugly), but nobody answered. So, I thought it was too long for people to read it and I made it shortened.

Comment: There is no need to leave a $x$ on a side. It is simpler (and less error prone) to consider $j(x):=h(x)-x\le0$. Find any value of $x$ such that $j(x)\le0$.

Comment: Where is this ugly monster coming from ?

Answer (score 1):

From what I read I infer that you want to disprove $h(x)\le x$, knowing that $\lim_{x\to 0}h(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to1} h(x)=5$. In fact $f$ and $g$, which are not disclosed, play no role here.

Then $\lim_{x\to 0}h(x)=0$ tells us nothing (because $\lim_{x\to 0}x=0$ as well), but $\lim_{x\to1} h(x)=5>1$ is enough to prove that there are values of $x$ such that $h(x)>x$ (take an $\epsilon$ such that $5-\epsilon>1$).

You could as well exhibit a single value of $x$ such that $h(x)>x$.

---

Anyway, make sure that your transformation from the $f,g$ representation to $h$ does not alter the comparison.

Comment: Yves Daoust. Thank you, and sorry. I had to modify the question to provide the function with correct values on the endpoints. Yes, it seems that the new question is to prove that $h(x)>x$. But, is this proof is sufficient to prove that $h$ is always greater than $x$? I mean, is it ti sufficient to disprove that $h(x)=0$ or $h(x)<0$?

Comment: @Mariya: conceptually that doesn't change anything to my answer.

Comment: @Mariya: "$h$ is always greater than $x$ ?": what, you never said *always* !?

Comment: $h>x$ comes form the first condition $f>g$, which I have to prove it. It seems that I should modify the question again.

Comment: If I am able to delete the post, I will do that and write a new one. It seems that it is not clear. I am sorry and thanks.